# ZK MVVM : Passing parameter to another viewmodel using <include>

Tags: mvvm, zk

What I want to do is passing value from `page1.zul` to `page2.zul` through `<include>` and `viewModel`.

From `page1.zul`, I have

```
<include processId="@bind(vm.selectedProcess.id)" src="@load('page2.zul')"></include>
```

And then it should pass to a `viewModel` in `page2.zul`

```
@Init
public void init(@ExecutionArgParam("processId") String processId){
    System.out.println("processInstanceId : " + processId);
}
```

However, I always get a null value. Any idea how to do this thing ? `page2.zul` looks something like this :

```
<div apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
    viewModel="@id('vm') @bind('com.mrye.viewModel')">

    <label value="@load(vm.processId)"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make distinguish names for Id's of the VM.

Then zul :

```
<div apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.mrye.viewModel', processId = parentVM.selectedProcess.id )">
```

And VM2:

```
@Init
public void init (@BindingParam("processId") MyObject processID) {
```

Edit after the comment :

As you can see in [this fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/2ffojfc/1-ZK-passing-parameters) it works, but your parameter has to be initialized.

If you want to have "live data" passed to other zul (not other viewmodel), you can use `@ref` or just use parentVM.
If the live data need's to be in the viewmodel itself, you can use a non visible textbox where you load the data from parentVM and save it in the includedVM just before some action happens.

See [updated fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1sv413r/2-ZK-passing-parameters) here.

Comment: I still get a null value. Based on the log, it seems like it will run the `VM2` and then only it will run the `VM1`. Means it will display before it actually bind the value.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can check

**Index.zul**

```
<?page title="URL Parameters Test" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>  
<zk>  
<window title="URL Parameters Test" border="normal">  

    <include src="header.zul?test=5" />  

</window>  
</zk>
```

In above code you can check it pass argument with URL here test is argument name and value=5

```
<?page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<zk>
<window border="none" width="100%" height="100%" apply="pkg$.HeaderComposer">

<label id="lblHeader" />

<div>
Load from EL [ <label value="${param.test}" />]
</div>
</window>
</zk>
```

In this page we used `${param.test}` to get the parameter passed in index.zul , HeaderComposer.java

```
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.*;  
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.*;  
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.util.*;  
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.ext.*;  
import org.zkoss.zk.au.*;  
import org.zkoss.zk.au.out.*;  
import org.zkoss.zul.*;  

public class HeaderComposer extends GenericForwardComposer{  


    Label lblHeader;  

    @Override  
    public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {  

        try {  
            super.doAfterCompose(comp);  
        }   
        catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  

        /* 
         * retrieve url parameters 
         */  
        String[] parameter = (String[]) param.get("test");  

        if (parameter != null)  
            lblHeader.setValue( "Congratulations! Your parameters value is " + parameter[0] );  
        else  
            lblHeader.setValue( "No parameters found. URL should be something like http://yourserver/yoursite/main.zul?parameter=param-value" );  
    }  
}
```

for more way you can check http://zkframeworkhint.blogspot.in/2014/05/zk-include-how-to-pass-and-get.html

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure on VM1 the value `vm.selectedProcess.id` is correctly initialized and it has a value, in the VM2 add the  `@AfterCompose` lifecycle annotation then on `@Init` get the value, according to your code this should work on VM2:

```
   Long processId;

   @AfterCompose
   public void initAfterCompose(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view) {
       Selectors.wireComponents(view, this, false);
   }

   @Init
   public void init() {
       //get dynamic attribut
       processId = (Long) Executions.getCurrent().getAttribute("processId");
   }
```